# Different numbering style for the same level in a multilevel list

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013

Is it possible to achieve the following with Multilevel Lists in Word:

#### 1. Heading

#### Part II.  Another Heading

#### Part III. Another Heading

#### 4. Another Heading

Ideally, I'd like to use "Heading 1" style for **1.**-style heading, and "Part Heading 1" - for **Part I**-style.

I tried defining "Part Heading 1" to be based on "Heading 1" and then changing the numbering scheme, but that doesn't continue the same list.